# How do you use Express middleware and requires() in route files?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm following [a tutorial that explains how to set up `passport`](http://www.sitepoint.com/local-authentication-using-passport-node-js/).

The problem is that the tutorial assumes all of your routes are in the main `app.js` file, but in my case, my routes are already defined in separate route files.

How can I make `passport` work properly on these routes?

Currently my routes are like this, in `app.js`:

```
var routes_main = require('./app/routes/index');
var routes_admin = require('./app/routes/admin');

//routes
app.use('/', routes_main);
app.use('/admin', routes_admin);
```

Comment: Can you show how your routes are set up and used in main file?

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy.

You will just add the passport middleware to the `app.use`:

```
app.use('/', passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect: '/'}), routes_main);
```

Comment: Oh cool. I didn't know about that syntax. In the tutorial, it says you need to put that middleware on the `.get` and .`post` functions

Comment: You can include multiple middlewares in app.use

Comment: Problem with this is, on failure, I want to redirect to a path within `routes_main`. So I need the authentication to happen in there

Comment: Then you should extract the view for the failed login view to another route which is not authenticated

Comment: That's an alright solution. But there's no way to use `passport` inside files other than my main one, `app.js`?

Comment: You can extract passport to a separate file and `require` it wherever you want, actually :)